# YOLOv4 custom model: is final.weights or last.weights better?

Tags: yolo, darknet, yolov4

I'm training a custom YOLOv4 model using darknet, and at the end of training it produces two files: `last.weights` and `final.weights`. What is the difference between them, and which one should I use? From the naming I'd guess `final.weights` is the best `best.weights` that was generated, but I can't find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference to [original Yolov4](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet), `last_weight` is not the best

```
(file yolo-obj_last.weights will be saved to the build\darknet\x64\backup\ for each 100 iterations)
```

And if you dive into source code, `final.weight` is saved after training (through all iterations)
The `best.weights` file is exactly the best weight you need
[image: yolov4 source code]

Comment: I appreciate you looking into the source, thank you. I'm a bit concerned that final might be just the final iteration (for later resumption of training), not the best weights (which are generated using a heuristic).

Comment: Are you sure don't have any `best.weight` file? Cause I've found this line of code `sprintf(buff, "%s/%s_best.weights", backup_directory, base);`

Comment: It produced a few best.weights along the way, but after the training was actually finished it only produced the `final` and `last` weights. The `best.weights` file is a few hours older than the others. I wonder if it just so happened in this training that the best weight was actually found before training finished?

Comment: Exactly, don't have any rule that the best is produced at the last. The `best.weights` file was the best. Because new `mAP` compared to old one and update if better, when updated, the `best.weights` file also was saved. So if new `mAP` was not good as old one, the `best.weights` file had older timestamp as the `last.weights` and `final.weights`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I ran 6k iterations, and it looks like the `best.weights` was generated around iteration !1800. It seems a bit weird that the best model would be that early in training though, doesn't it?

Comment: It really makes sense. It means that you could stop early because the more iterations you train, the more accuracy you lost, and you wasted time too

Comment: @Nathan I've updated my answer, you should check it, especially the image